# DataTables/server-side processing with hidden row/row ID is showing as the image

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables, along with jquery-datatables-editable, using server-side processing and a hidden details row.

It is working well, except each row is given an 'id' that equals the clickable image that reveals the hidden details row. For example, each row in the table (viewed from firebug or chrome element inspector) looks like this:

```
<tr id="&lt;img src=&quot;images/details_open.png&quot;&gt;" class="odd">
<td class="center"><img src="images/details_open.png"></td>
<td class=" sorting_1">Carpet By Joe</td>
<td class="">Joe</td><td class="">123-456-7890</td>
<td class="">ad@here.com</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var what = "customer";
    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        //"bProcessing" : true,
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource" : "lib/gen.php?what=" + what,

        "aoColumns" : [{
            "sClass" : "center",
            "bSortable" : false,
        }, {
            "sName" : "name",
            "mData" : "2"
        }, {
            "sName" : "contact",
            "mData" : "3"
        }, {
            "sName" : "phone",
            "mData" : "4"
        }, {
            "sName" : "email",
            "mData" : "5"
        }],
        "aaSorting" : [[1, 'desc']]
    }).makeEditable({

        sUpdateURL : "lib/edit.php?what=" + what + "&action=edit",
        sAddURL : "lib/edit.php?what=" + what + "&action=add",
        sDeleteURL : "DeleteData.php",
        sAddDeleteToolbarSelector : ".dataTables_length",
        "oAddNewRowFormOptions" : {
            "title" : "Add A New Customer",
            "width" : 400,
            "height" : 450
        },
        "aoColumns" : [null, {
            cssclass : 'required'
        }, {
            indicator : "<img src='images/indicator.gif'>",
            tooltip : "Doubleclick to edit...",
            event : "dblclick",
            style : "inherit",

        }]
    });

    /* Formating function for row details */
    function fnFormatDetails(nTr) {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
        //var id = aData[1];
        var sOut = '<div>';
        var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
        sOut += '<tr><th width="75" align="left">&nbsp;</th><th width="300" align="left">Address Information</th><th align="left">Notes</th></tr>';
        sOut += '<tr><td><strong>Address: </strong></td><td class="5"><div class="edittable">' + aData[6] + '</div></td><td  style="vertical-align: top;" class="9" rowspan="4"><div class="edittextarea">' + aData[10] + '</div></td></tr>';
        sOut += '<tr><td><strong>City: </strong></td><td class="6"><div class="edittable">' + aData[7] + '</div></td></tr>';
        sOut += '<tr><td><strong>State: </strong></td><td class="7"><div class="edittable">' + aData[8] + '</div></td></tr>';
        sOut += '<tr><td><strong>Zip: </strong></td><td class="8"><div class="edittable">' + aData[9] + '</div></td></tr>';
        sOut += '</table>';
        return sOut;
    }


    $('#example tbody td img').live('click', function() {
        var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        if (this.src.match('details_close')) {
            /* This row is already open - close it */
            this.src = "images/details_open.png";
            oTable.fnClose(nTr);
        } else {
            /* Open this row */
            this.src = "images/details_close.png";
            oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details');
            //make_jeditable(nTr);
        }
    });

});
```

Here is the output from my server side processing (the json is at the bottom, which is what is passed to to datatables, the array is for readability):

```
Array
(
    [sEcho] => 0
    [iTotalRecords] => 3
    [iTotalDisplayRecords] => 3
    [aaData] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <img src="images/details_open.png">
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => Company 1
                    [3] => Joe Bob
                    [4] => 123-456-7890
                    [5] => admin@here.com
                    [6] => 123 My Way
                    [7] => Fayetteville
                    [8] => AR
                    [9] => 12345
                    [10] => This is a note for this customer, 1
                    [extra] => hrmll
                    [DT_RowId] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <img src="images/details_open.png">
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => Aaron's Floor Cleaning
                    [3] => Aaron Man
                    [4] => (133) 456-7890
                    [5] => email@there.com
                    [6] => 321. There Way
                    [7] => Scottsdale
                    [8] => AR
                    [9] => 54327
                    [10] => This is another note, but about another customer, 36

                    [extra] => hrmll
                    [DT_RowId] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <img src="images/details_open.png">
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => Carpet By Joe
                    [3] => Joe
                    [4] => 123-456-7890
                    [5] => ad@here.com
                    [6] => 123 SW Way Over St.
                    [7] => Springfield
                    [8] => AL
                    [9] => 87654
                    [10] => This is a note here.
                    [extra] => hrmll
                    [DT_RowId] => 4
                )

        )

)

{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"3","iTotalDisplayRecords":"3","aaData":[{"0":"<img src=\"images\/details_open.png\">","1":"1","2":"Company 1","3":"Joe Bob","4":"123-456-7890","5":"admin@here.com","6":"123 My Way","7":"Fayetteville","8":"AR","9":"12345","10":"This is a note for this customer, 1","extra":"hrmll","DT_RowId":"1"},{"0":"<img src=\"images\/details_open.png\">","1":"2","2":"Aaron's Floor Cleaning","3":"Aaron Man","4":"(133) 456-7890","5":"email@there.com","6":"321. There Way","7":"Scottsdale","8":"AR","9":"54327","10":"This is another note, but about another customer, 36\n","extra":"hrmll","DT_RowId":"2"},{"0":"<img src=\"images\/details_open.png\">","1":"4","2":"Carpet By Joe","3":"Joe","4":"123-456-7890","5":"ad@here.com","6":"123 SW Way Over St.","7":"Springfield","8":"AL","9":"87654","10":"This is a note here.","extra":"hrmll","DT_RowId":"4"}]}
```

Here is the HTML fot the table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="4%"></th>
        <th width="25%">Customer Name</th>
        <th width="20%">Contact</th>
        <th width="20%">Phone</th>
        <th width="25%">Email</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

The returned info has the 'DT_RowId' item, but that is not parsed into the row's id as it should. Please let me know if I can provide any further info.

Edit:

Aktee, you are a genius.

I removed this:

```
[0] => <img src="images/details_open.png">
```

from the server side processing altogether, and by your suggestion the top of my javascript now looks like:

```
"aoColumns" : [{
    "sClass" : "center",
    "mData": function () {
        return '<img src="images/details_open.png">';
 },
    "bSortable" : false
},
```

I noticed in the docs it mentions that 'mData' is the newer version of 'mDataProp', so I used it instead. Your other suggestions are leading me to rethink some of my other code. Thank you very much.

Comment: I bet the `<tr id="` causes something to choke

Comment: <tr id='' is automatically generated by the datatables plugin.

Comment: of note: "Live" is a deprecated jQuery function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like dataTable is using the [0] as id name. This is bad. Try pushing it down last..

Or use these tips:

- Use mDataProp instead of mData. You will have so much more control and it's going to be much more logical when reading the code. Also, when adding something, you won't have to make sure you have the correct index.

  ```
  aoColumns: [
     { mDataProp: "customername", bSortable: true },
     { mDataProp: "contact", bSortable: true },
  ]
  ```

  And the JSON output would be something like

  ```
  [aaData] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [company] => Company 1
              [customername] => Joe Bob
  ```
- I noticed you always have src="images/details_open.png" as [0]. This is kinda a waste of bandwith. Instead, try this

  ```
  aoColumns: [

      [...]

     { mDataProp: function(x) {
        return '<img src="images/details_open.png">';
     }, bSortable: true },

  ]
  ```

  This is quite useful, because you can do stuff like this!

  ```
  aoColumns: [

      [...]

     { mDataProp: function(x) {
        return '<img src="images/details_open.png" data-id="' + x.id + '">';
     }, bSortable: true },

  ]
  ```

  - If you want to edit each row, use fnDrawCallBack...

    ```
     fnDrawCallback: function ( oSettings ) {
             if ( oSettings.aiDisplay.length == 0 ) {
                 return;
             }

             var TRs = $('#lst_production tbody tr');
             var iColspan = TRs[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length;

             for ( var i=0 ; i<TRs.length ; i++ ) {

                 var iDisplayIndex = oSettings._iDisplayStart + i;
                 data = oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[iDisplayIndex] ]._aData;

                 // add the ID to the row
                 $(TRs[i]).attr("id", data.id);

                 // add class red-background if customer is from AR
                 if (data.state == 'AR') {
                     $(TRs[i]).addClass("red-background");
                 }

             }
         },
    ```

Comment: Thank you so much, I made edits to the OP to show exactly what I did, but your comments were the source. Thank you!!!!